# android send broadcast message from contentobserver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contentresolver

I have a class of `contentobserver`, I want to send broasdcast message from `contentobserver`. But when its call app crash and I see the logcate context is `null` please tell me how can I send message from `contentresolver`.
Here is my code:

```
public class SettingsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    Context context;
    public SettingsContentObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        //Profile1Activity.profile1(context);

        Intent i = new Intent("settingschanged");
        context.sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the complete code where and how are you assigning context?

Comment: this is the complete code

Comment: Well then context is going to be null, you haven't yet supplied it with any context whatsoever to begin with, you are trying to call a method on a null object reference. Assign the context some value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to pass the application context to the ContentObserver?

```
public class SettingsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    Context mContext;
    public SettingsContentObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
        super(handler);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        //Profile1Activity.profile1(context);

        Intent i = new Intent("settingschanged");
        mContext.sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! If you are happy with the solution, please accept the answer.